# Contrast to ANOVA with interaction term

Tags: r, anova, interaction, contrasts

I need to fit orthogonal contrasts to the following model. The following example data.

```
   rep <- c(rep( 1, 15), rep(2, 15))
    parent1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4)
    parent2 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5,1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5)
    yld <- c(10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 12, 13, 14, 15, 13, 14, 15, 14, 15, 15,11, 13, 12, 13, 15, 14, 12, 13, 15, 12, 15, 15, 13, 15, 16)
    mydf <- data.frame(rep, parent1, parent2, yld)
    mydf$parent1 <- as.factor(mydf$parent1)
    mydf$parent2 <- as.factor(mydf$parent2)
```

Parent1 and Parent2 are factors.

```
    mode11 <- lm(yld ~ rep + parent1:parent2, data = mydf)
    anova(mode11)
```

I need to fit contrasts, I suppose the order 
of the treatments for the coefficients for the interaction is:

```
Parent1    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4    
Parent2    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5 

# contrasts for Parent1:Parent2 interaction 
mycontrast <- c(-4, -4, -4, -4, 4,  2, 2, 2, 2, 2,  2, 2, 2, 2,2)
```

I want to apply above orthogonal contrasts (mycontrasts). I am used to SAS to this short of analysis however not in R.  I have two questions:

(a) How can I properly apply contrast to above model?

(b) I am concerned what is order of the treatments ( see my assumed orders, are they right?) , while writing coefficients - I assume this should be either alphabetical or  order in file.

Comment: Could you give us more details on what you are trying to test and what your experimental design is? I'm wondering (1) why you want to include an interaction term without the corresponding main effects (i.e., `yld ~ rep + parent1:parent2` instead of `yld ~ rep + parent1*parent2`), and (2) why you consider only one contrast for the interaction since this term has 14 DF in your model (unless you're interested in a specific post-hoc contrast).